# Document.getFilePropertiesAsync method of Excel web api fails in unsaved Excel document

Tags: excel, office-js

Using Excel Version 1803 (Build 912xxxxx) the method getFilePropertiesAsync doesnt return a succes when executed on an unsaved file.  I have executed the code snippet in ScriptLab on an unsaved Excel document. The code works fine if executed in a saved Excel document.

```
Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    if ((asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)) {
        var savedURL = asyncResult.value.url;
        if (!(savedURL === 'undefined')) {
            console.log("Not undefined save location");
            if (!(savedURL == null)) {
                console.log("Not null save location");
                console.log(savedURL);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Call failed");
    }
});
```

The same snippet works in Word even with unsaved documents and as per the API [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync.md) should work in Excel as well. Is this a missing feature in the Excel API?

Answer (score 1):

For now it looks like checking for (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) seems to be the only way to get around this problem